# matching two array columns postgresql-9.4-

Tags: sql, arrays, database, postgresql-9.4

In the same row;

```
Array column 1 has {2,4,5} value  
Array column 2 has {4,8,9} value
```

What i want to do is to query rows in a table that matches at least one number in two array columns which match example above; number 4 provides this match.

How can i query that, of course for every 2 array columns in every row in the table? I want to select rows matching 2 array columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install the [`intarray`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html) extension this becomes easy, you can use the `&` operator to get the intersection between two arrays:

```
with data (col1, col2) as (
  values 
    (array[3,4,5], array[4,8,9]), 
    (array[1,2,3,4], array[6,5,1]),
    (array[1,2,3,4], array[7,8,9,10]) 
)
select col1 & col2
from data 
where cardinality(col1 & col2) > 0;
```

returns:

```
common_elements
---------------
{4}            
{1}
```

**Edit**

To do this without the extension or with `bigint` arrays, you can unnest both columns into sets and then do the intersection on those sets. This requires a primary key (or unique) column on the table (which you didn't mention)

```
with data (id, col1, col2) as (
  values 
    (1, array[3,4,5]::bigint[], array[4,8,9]::bigint[]), 
    (2, array[1,2,3,4]::bigint[], array[6,5,1]::bigint[]),
    (3, array[1,2,3,4]::bigint[], array[7,8,9,10]::bigint[]) 
)
select id, array_agg(element) as elements
from (
  select id, unnest(col1) as element
  from data 
  intersect
  select id, unnest(col2)
  from data
) t
group by id;
```

returns:

```
id | elements
---+---------
 1 | {4}
 2 | {1}
```

Comment: thanks:)...and i wonder how can i do that without this extension?

Comment: @lowdegeneration: why? It makes it easy and efficient. And the extension is part of the standard Postgres installation. All you need to do is `create extension intarray;`

Comment: it doen't work with bigint[] right? Because i get error when i use bigint type in array.

Comment: @lowdegeneration: looks like it. See my edit for a different solution